# Question about Thm 1.4.4 in ANT Alaca/Williams

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

[image]
[image]

I am studying Introductory ANT by Alaca/Williams, p12, theorem 1.4.4:

"Let $m$ be a nonsquare integer such that $\mathbb {Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt {m}$ is a PID. Let $p $ be an odd prime for which the Legendre symbol $\left (\frac {m}{p}\right)=1. $ Then there exist integers such that $ p=u^2-mv^2$ if $m <0$, or if ( ... )"

Considering that $\mathbb {Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt {-11} \ $  is a PID and that $\left (\frac {-11}{23}\right)=1 \ $  I would have expected to be able to find integers $ u, v $ such that $23=u^2+11v^2$  but I can't. Please explain what I do wrong or misunderstand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overlooked the fact that $-11 = 1 \mod 4$. (This is somewhere in that first chapter, but I don't have the book with me at the moment).

That means you also have to look at the so-called "half-integers," and you're looking to solve $23 = \frac{u^2}{4} + \frac{11v^2}{4}$. The answer is $u = \pm9, v = \pm1$. Indeed, $$\left(\frac{9}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{-11}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{9}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-11}}{2}\right) = 23.$$

Comment: Thank you, Alonso. The 1 mod 4 case is described in Thm 1.4.5 however. Looking at both theorems ( I added pics of the relevant pages ) I would assume 1.4.4 applies to all, irrelevant the remainder mod 4. What do you think?

Comment: I think this might be precisely the kind of thing that causes some people to be jerks about the distinction between $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})}$. The latter is a PID, the former is not since $2$ and $3$ are prime in it yet $2^2 \times 3 = (1 - \sqrt{-11})(1 + \sqrt{-11})$.

Comment: As I think more about it, I think it's possible that without the "half-integers," if $m \equiv 1 \mod 4$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ just can't be a PID, and therefore Theorem 1.4.4 doesn't need to make special mention of it. But it wouldn't hurt if it did, it would make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

That book really needs a Chapter 0, in my opinion. If you purport to write an *introduction* to algebraic number theory, you can't assume your readers know anything other than elementary number theory, basic algebra and basic set theory. And by "basic algebra," I mean really basic, like solving an equation in one variable, multiplying binomials and using the quadratic formula to solve $ax^2 + bx + c$. My proposed Chapter 0 would cover things like the difference between algebraic numbers and algebraic integers; what is a homomorphism, isomorphism, and all those whatever-morphisms; and aspects of notation, like why you bother to write $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt{m}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$, and why would anyone would want to go through the trouble of defining $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ and then $\mathcal{O}_K$.

But anyway, it would do you a lot of good to carefully reread Example 1.1.5. Still, I would add to Theorem 1.4.4 the stricture that $m \not\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (understanding of course that $\mu(m) \neq 0$ [the Möbius function]). If $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is not integrally closed, then it can't be a PID. And if $m \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we know for a fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is not integrally closed and that it is a subdomain of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}]$, or $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})}$. So Theorem 1.4.4 does not apply in this case, and that is why it is immediately followed by Theorem 1.4.5.

The reason you can't find a solution to $u^2 + 11v^2 = 23$ in integers is because there is no such solution to be found. Try the following query on Wolfram Alpha: `solve u^2 + 11v^2 = 23 in integers`. Now try this one: `solve u^2/4 + (11v^2)/4 = 23 in integers`. That works because the norm of an algebraic integer in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2}]$ is $\frac{u^2 + mv^2}{4}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})}$ is a principal ideal domain, and that domain includes $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-11}]$ as a subdomain.

Now, I can't guarantee that you will *never* find an example of a non-PID where nevertheless one particular case of $(\frac{m}{p}) = 1$ does have a solution for $u^2 - mv^2 = p$. But if there is such a case, I do guarantee that in that same non-PID you will also find a case where that does not hold.

Comment: I think this book wasn't such a good choice after all, not for me anyway,I will study 'Lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers' by Hecke and a recent book 'Algebraic theory of quadratic numbers' by Trifković instead.